SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table - laravel 11
I'm kind of new to laravel, and get this error while I was trying store some data:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: main.user

my code is this:
$club = new Club();
$club->name = $request->name;
$club->user_id = $request->id;
$club->status = true;
$club->save();
$success = 'تمت إضافة وتفعيل النادي بنجاح';

return view('admin.clubs.new_club', compact('success'));

it point to save() as the cause of the error but I don't know why. I have the same form but for user and it works

Maybe you haven't executed the migrations?

Hello, Can you run php artisan db:table user,  and check if you can see its structure

I have done php artisan migrate  as I have another page which insert a user info (it works well)

If you have another page where this does work, that means there must be something different with the way you're doing it here compared to the working one. So I'd double-check the two implementations against each other. However, as the question stands now, it does not provide enough information for anyone to provide a clear answer.

Thank you for your help, I figure it out, I was using this code:
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('user');

The mistake I have done is I wrote user instead of users
